# Sinatra Restarting Webrick Server after ctrl-c

Tags: ruby, sinatra, webrick

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'rubygems'

class TestServer < Sinatra::Application
set :port, 22340
    get '/' do
        "Hello World"
    end
    run! if app_file == $0
end
```

Very Simple application with Ruby 2.0.0-p0 and Sinatra 1.4.2

When I ctrl-c the webrick server restarts on the default port... see output below

```
LM-BOS-00715009:server joshughes$ ruby test.rb 
[2013-04-19 16:07:48] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-04-19 16:07:48] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-02-24) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]
== Sinatra/1.4.2 has taken the stage on 22340 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2013-04-19 16:07:48] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=63798 port=22340
^C
== Sinatra has ended his set (crowd applauds)
[2013-04-19 16:07:56] INFO  going to shutdown ...
[2013-04-19 16:07:56] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
[2013-04-19 16:07:56] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-04-19 16:07:56] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-02-24) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]
== Sinatra/1.4.2 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2013-04-19 16:07:56] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=63798 port=4567
^C
```

Can anyone help me on what might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is you’re not correctly using the [Sinatra modular style](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Modular%20vs.%20Classic%20Style). Rather than requiring `sinatra` and inheriting from `Sinatra::Application` you should require `sinatra/base` and inherit from `Sinatra::Base`.

What’s happening is this. You require plain `sinatra`, which in turn requires `sinatra/main`. This file [adds an `at_exit` handler that runs the built in server](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.4.2/lib/sinatra/main.rb#L25) (unless you disable it). However you also explicitly call `run!` in your own code, so the server starts because of  your call, then when you exit that the `at_exit` handler starts the server again. Requiring `sinatra/base` doesn’t start the built-in server at exit, so you’ll only have your own explicit call to `run!`.

```
require 'sinatra/base' # change here
require 'rubygems'

class TestServer < Sinatra::Base # and here
  set :port, 22340
  get '/' do
    "Hello World"
  end
  run! if app_file == $0
end
```